# How to filter out from a database from the following mongo object

Tags: python, mongodb

I have a database in which objects are listed as below

```
{'documents': [{'tags': ['Procedures', 'Cardiac', 'ECG', None],
   '_id': ObjectId('5cf602f74beb6e2a391b7d95'),
   'key': 'images/333213095:2019-06-04T05:34:46.862Z.jpg',
   'reportedAt': datetime.datetime(2019, 6, 4, 4, 30),
   'updatedAt': datetime.datetime(2019, 6, 4, 5, 34, 47, 907000),
   'createdAt': datetime.datetime(2019, 6, 4, 5, 34, 47, 907000)},
  {'tags': ['Documents', 'Admission notes', None, None],
   '_id': ObjectId('5cf60fa84beb6e46bc1b7dcc'),
   'key': 'images/2851467532:2019-06-04T06:28:55.398Z.jpg',
   'reportedAt': datetime.datetime(2019, 6, 4, 4, 30),
   'updatedAt': datetime.datetime(2019, 6, 4, 6, 28, 56, 34000),
   'createdAt': datetime.datetime(2019, 6, 4, 6, 28, 56, 34000)},
  {'tags': ['Documents', 'Admission notes', None, None],
   '_id': ObjectId('5cf60fb74beb6eac251b7dcf'),
   'key': 'images/3976429268:2019-06-04T06:29:11.269Z.jpg',
   'reportedAt': datetime.datetime(2019, 6, 4, 4, 30),
   'updatedAt': datetime.datetime(2019, 6, 4, 6, 29, 11, 724000),
   'createdAt': datetime.datetime(2019, 6, 4, 6, 29, 11, 724000)},
  {'tags': ['Documents', 'Admission notes', None, None],
   '_id': ObjectId('5cf60fd44beb6e27081b7dd2'),
   'key': 'images/1426882813:2019-06-04T06:29:40.078Z.jpg',
   'reportedAt': datetime.datetime(2019, 6, 4, 4, 30),
   'updatedAt': datetime.datetime(2019, 6, 4, 6, 29, 40, 447000),
   'createdAt': datetime.datetime(2019, 6, 4, 6, 29, 40, 447000)},
  {'tags': ['Blood', 'Hematology', 'CBC', None],
   '_id': ObjectId('5cf6add44beb6e1c001b99fb'),
   'key': '',
   'attributes': {'Hb': '12.8',
    'Platelet': '106000',
    'MCV': '92.6',
    'Neutrophils': '82',
    'Eosinophil': '02',
    'Lymphocytes': '13',
    'Atypical': '00',
    'Total count': '10330',
    'Basophils': '00'},
   'reportedAt': datetime.datetime(2019, 6, 4, 17, 43, 35, 960000),
   'updatedAt': datetime.datetime(2019, 6, 4, 17, 43, 48, 306000),
   'createdAt': datetime.datetime(2019, 6, 4, 17, 43, 48, 306000)}
```

I need to filter out all records which has the tag

```
'tags': ['Blood', 'Hematology', 'CBC', None]
```

I tried the following code

```
list(db2.patients.find({'CPMRN':mrn1, 'documents.tags':['Blood', 'Hematology', 'CBC', None]}, {('documents'):1, '_id':0}))
```

But it is not working (not showing an error, but the filtered result is not what I wanted).

When I try this

```
list(db2.patients.find({'CPMRN':mrn1, 'documents.tags':'[Blood, Hematology, CBC, None]'}, {('documents'):1, '_id':0}))
```

It is giving an empty list as result

How should I be phrasing my query when it is a list of strings?

Thank you very much

Comment: I dont see CPMRN in the data you provided. What am I missing?

Comment: What I have presented here is only part of the data.. There is CPMRN I could not fit in here.. database is pretty huge..

Answer (score 0):

i think the problem is with your project in find query.

you are wrapping 'documents' in parenthesis`()`, but you should pass it without parenthesis.

Try this :

```
db2.patients.find({
    'CPMRN':mrn1, 
    'documents.tags':['Blood', 'Hematology', 'CBC', None]
}, {
    'documents':1, 
    '_id':0
})
```

You can also try with [$all](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/all):

```
db2.patients.find({
    'CPMRN':mrn1, 
    'documents.tags':{$all : ['Blood', 'Hematology', 'CBC', None]}
}, {
    'documents':1, 
    '_id':0
})
```